# Understanding Lazy Evaluation in C#

Tags: c#, linq, lazy-evaluation

I have a code like this

```
 class Context
    {
        public List<Student> lists;
        public Context()
        {
            lists = new List<Student>() {
                new Student { Name="foo",Standard="first",subjects=new Subjects { Geography=50,History=81,Science=70} },
                new Student { Name="carl",Standard="first",subjects=new Subjects { Geography=40,History=51,Science=50} },
                new Student { Name="ben",Standard="first",subjects=new Subjects { Geography=30,History=91,Science=60} },
                new Student { Name="peter",Standard="first",subjects=new Subjects { Geography=80,History=71,Science=40} }              
            };
        }
    }
    class Client
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Student> lists = new Context().lists;
            var result = lists.Where(x => x.subjects.History > 60);
            lists.Add(new Student { Name = "tan", Standard = "first", subjects = new Subjects { Geography = 40, History = 81, Science = 60 } });
            lists.Add(new Student { Name = "ran", Standard = "first", subjects = new Subjects { Geography = 30, History = 70, Science = 50 } });
            lists.Add(new Student { Name = "ranky", Standard = "first", subjects = new Subjects { Geography = 20, History = 31, Science = 40 } });
            lists.Add(new Student { Name = "franky", Standard = "first", subjects = new Subjects { Geography = 50, History = 51, Science = 30 } });
            foreach (var data in result) {
            Console.WriteLine(data);
        }
        }
    }
```

now while debugging, before adding some element and when i place mouse over the variable, i get the result like this

[image]

after adding some elements to the lists, when i hover over the variable i get the result like this

[image]
but according to Lazy Execution concept, it loads the data when it reaches the foreach method, then why is the data already loaded and be seen in the debugger. Am I missing something towards understanding Lazy Evaluation
UPDATE 1
According to the previous regarding my screenshot, if clicking on "Results view" forced to load the data then, here is my second scenerio where i just load the data, which can been seen form the screenshot

[image]
but when the debugger moves to the next element the count increases.

[image]
isn't it suppose to load the data when a call is made using a foreach? Please help me to understand how the Lazy Evaluation works. Thank you.

Comment: The code you've quoted in your question looks nothing like the screenshot you've shown. Please provide a [mcve], and show the output from *that* (which can just be text again - there's no need for a screenshot at all)

Comment: ok, just a sec... thank you for the help

Comment: `Concat` does not modify `numbers`, it *returns* a new list that is modified. You probably want, `result = numbers.Concat(num2);` in place of `numbers.Concat(num2);`.

Comment: Nothing to do with lazy eval.  Concat() has a return value, you need to use it if you want to take advantage of what it does.

Comment: @JonSkeet sir, i have updated my question, please have a look at it, thank you

Comment: @JonSkeet i have updated my question please have a look at it, thank you

Comment: go ahead and mark me down but at least tell me what is wrong with my question, I am not able to understand the logic that is the reason i have asked the question so that i could get help, marking me down wont help any one. if i would have known the answer at the first place i wouldn't have spend time to post one

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're not assigning the results of the concatenation to anything:

```
numbers.Concat(num2);
```

That should be:

```
numbers = numbers.Concat(num2).ToArray();
```

Comment: This won't compile since `numbers` is typed as `int[]` instead of `IEnumerable<int>`.

Comment: @MichaelLiu please try the code you would be amazed

Comment: i have updated my question please have a look at it, thank you

Comment: @LijinJohn "why is the data already loaded and be seen in the debugger." Because your forced it to evaluate. You can see the text even in your screenshot. "Results View - Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable."

Comment: @itsme86 you mean to say that clicking on "Results View" forced the data to load?

Comment: @itsme86 i have updated the question please have a look at it, thank you